# Convert any Date String Format to a specific date format string

Tags: python, sorting, parsing, datetime, datetime-format

I am making a generic tool which can take up any csv file.I have a csv file which looks something like this. The first row is the column name and the second row is the type of variable.
    **sam.csv**

```
Time,M1,M2,M3,CityName
temp,num,num,num,city
20-06-13,19,20,0,aligarh
20-02-13,25,42,7,agra
20-03-13,23,35,4,aligarh
20-03-13,21,32,3,allahabad
20-03-13,17,27,1,aligarh
20-02-13,16,40,5,aligarh
```

Other CSV file looks like:

```
Time,M1,M2,M3,CityName
temp,num,num,num,city
20/8/16,789,300,10,new york
12/6/17,464,67,23,delhi
12/6/17,904,98,78,delhi
```

So, there could be any date format or it could be a time stamp.I want to convert it to "20-May-13" or "%d-%b-%y" format string everytime and sort the column from oldest date to the newest date. I have been able to search the column name where the type is "temp" and try to convert it to the required format but all the methods require me to specify the original format which is not possible in my case.
    Code--
    import csv
import time
from datetime import datetime,date
import pandas as pd
import dateutil
from dateutil.parser import parse

```
filename = 'sam.csv'
data_date = pd.read_csv(filename)
column_name = data_date.ix[:, data_date.loc[0] == "temp"]
column_work = column_name.iloc[1:]
column_some = column_work.iloc[:,0]
default_date = datetime.combine(date.today(), datetime.min.time()).replace(day=1)
for line in column_some:
        print(parse(line[0], default=default_date).strftime("%d-%b-%y"))
```

In "sam.csv", the dates are in 2013. But in my output it gives the correct format but all the 6 dates as 2-Mar-2018

Comment: You need to share your attempt on SO otherwise question will be closed.

Comment: You could try pandas `to_datetime`

Comment: There's no way to convert _any_ date string format without some additional information, because that's ambiguous. Does `02-03-18` mean European 2 March or American 3 Feb? Is `18-03-17` European 18 March 2017 or Japanese 17 March 2018?

Comment: I can give you some inputs about it. First list out all the date time formats that you want to support then write regex for them, then use these regex to figure out the format, then create a mapping of datetime strings to format them to convert to your desired format

Comment: If you have a list of specific formats, you can use the `datetime` module in the standard library and try various `strptime` calls and then `strftime` the one that works, or use a third-party library like `dateutil` that automates some of that work. Pick one, try to do exactly what you want with it, and if you get stuck, you can ask a question on SO, but you can't expect someone to guess what you might want and then write your code for you.

Comment: Also, keep the value as a `datetime` or `date` object during your processing; only do the conversion at input and at output. It's a lot easier to sort by `datetime` (which automatically compare exactly the way you'd want) than by `%d-%b-%y` strings (which you have to write a key function for that ultimately either converts back to `datetime` or does an equivalent amount of custom work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **[dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil)** library for converting any date format to your required format.

**Ex:**

```
import csv
from dateutil.parser import parse
p = "PATH_TO_YOUR_CSV.csv"      #I have used your sample data to test. 

with open(p, "r") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    next(reader)     #Skip Header
    next(reader)     #Skip Header
    for line in reader:
        print(parse(line[0]).strftime("%d-%B-%y"))    #Parse Date and convert it to date-month-year
```

**Output:**

```
20-June-13
20-February-13
20-March-13
20-March-13
20-March-13
20-February-13
20-August-16
06-December-17
06-December-17
```

**[MoreInfo on Dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)**

Comment: Thanks! @Rakesh I tried using this but it gives me dates in 2018 but my original data has dates in 2013. I have updated the code in the question. Please have a look.

Comment: Try removing the `default` in parse

Comment: It gives me the same output after removing

Comment: Can you post the content of `column_some`

Comment: `20-06-13
20-02-13
20-03-13
20-03-13
20-03-13
20-02-13
Name: Time Slot, dtype: object`

Comment: oh its a dataframe. in that case you do not need to do `line[0]` just `line`